# Original Chinese text to Lau Tzu's quotation

Tags: translation

I read this quotation when I was reading some English paper, I am really curious to know what is its original Chinese text:

> In pursuit of knowledge, every day something is acquired; in pursuit of wisdom, every day something is dropped. -- Lau Tzu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `为学日益，为道日损`.

> 为学日益，为道日损，损之又损，以至于无为，无为而无不为。取天下常以无事，及其有事，不足以取天下。
>
> ——老子《道德经》第四十八章